# Flipped Bitmap from Twain

Tags: c#, bitmap, ocr, twain, scanning

I'm currently getting scanned pages through Twain and transforming the pages to `Bitmap`, using the [BitmapRenderer](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet/blob/master/src/TwainDotNet/Win32/BitmapRenderer.cs) of [twaindotnet project](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet), as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13048612/922977).

My scanner allows me to scan recto and verso.
When I scan recto only pages, it works like a charm: the generated bitmaps are perfect. But when it scans recto-verso, the bitmap are flipped . Sometimes vertically, sometimes horizontally.

I can't use the `Bitmap.RotateFlip()` method because the effect doesn't concern each picture, but only when recto-verso pages.

I've tried the `Bitmap.FromHbitmap()` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766722/create-and-save-a-bitmap-from-an-intptr-c-sharp) or the default constructor, but it throws an error related to GDI+.

I'm pretty sure the issue is where the bitmap is converted from the pointer, in the BitmapRenderer class. Here is the code (I did not include the `Dispose()` methods for clarity purpose) :

```
public class BitmapRenderer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IntPtr _picturePointer;
    private readonly IntPtr _bitmapPointer;
    private readonly IntPtr _pixelInfoPointer;
    private Rectangle _rectangle;
    private readonly BitmapInfoHeader _bitmapInfo;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BitmapRenderer"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="picturePointer_">The picture pointer.</param>
    public BitmapRenderer(IntPtr picturePointer_)
    {
        _picturePointer = picturePointer_;
        _bitmapPointer = Kernel32Native.GlobalLock(picturePointer_);

        _bitmapInfo = new BitmapInfoHeader();
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(_bitmapPointer, _bitmapInfo);

        _rectangle = new Rectangle();
        _rectangle.X = _rectangle.Y = 0;
        _rectangle.Width = _bitmapInfo.Width;
        _rectangle.Height = _bitmapInfo.Height;

        if (_bitmapInfo.SizeImage == 0)
        {
            _bitmapInfo.SizeImage = ((((_bitmapInfo.Width*_bitmapInfo.BitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3)*
                                    _bitmapInfo.Height;
        }

        // The following code only works on x86
        Debug.Assert(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (IntPtr)) == 4);

        int pixelInfoPointer = _bitmapInfo.ClrUsed;
        if ((pixelInfoPointer == 0) && (_bitmapInfo.BitCount <= 8))
            pixelInfoPointer = 1 << _bitmapInfo.BitCount;

        pixelInfoPointer = (pixelInfoPointer*4) + _bitmapInfo.Size + _bitmapPointer.ToInt32();

        _pixelInfoPointer = new IntPtr(pixelInfoPointer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Renders to bitmap.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Bitmap RenderToBitmap()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(_rectangle.Width, _rectangle.Height);

        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            IntPtr hdc = graphics.GetHdc();
            try
            {
                Gdi32Native.SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, _rectangle.Width, _rectangle.Height,
                                              0, 0, 0, _rectangle.Height, _pixelInfoPointer, _bitmapPointer, 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
            }
        }
        bitmap.SetResolution(PpmToDpi(_bitmapInfo.XPelsPerMeter), PpmToDpi(_bitmapInfo.YPelsPerMeter));
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static float PpmToDpi(double pixelsPerMeter_)
    {
        double pixelsPerMillimeter = pixelsPerMeter_/1000.0;
        double dotsPerInch = pixelsPerMillimeter*25.4;
        return (float) Math.Round(dotsPerInch, 2);
    }
```

I don't understand where this is from or how to solve it.

### EDIT

Well, it appears this situation is not related to [twain](/questions/tagged/twain) conversion to bitmap (the issue is not from [twaindotnet project](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet) at all).

It only occurs with handwritten pages. **This is an automatic OCR issue**.
Does someone know how to disable OCR for handwritten document ?

Comment: You really don't know when it's flipped vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Nope, otherwise it would be easy. Maybe there is a way, but I hardly see how and where

Comment: I recommend this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280408/how-do-i-ask-a-question-regarding-a-heisenbug?cb=1 but I can't help you with this amount of informations :/

Comment: Thanks for your comment Thomas. I've edited my post, I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Does it happen at all on any other application? It might be a scanner twain driver issue (in which case it's not possible that a twain library could make it go away). Which scanner is it?

Comment: It's a Fujitsu fi-7160. It occurs only with handwritten pages, so it is an OCR issue. I don't know how to disable this OCR check. Any idea ?